# Update Duplicates in one table basis another with unique id

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with few common columns and an ID column. I need to update the Id column in Table1 from another table Table2. But there is duplicity in Table2 which is leading to duplicate updation in Table1.

```
create table x_a1 
( col1 text,
 col2 text,
 col_id integer
);
create table x_a2
( col1 text,
 col2 text,
 col_id integer
);
insert into x_a1 values('A1','B1',1);
insert into x_a1 values('A1','B1',2);
insert into x_a1 values('A1','B1',3);
insert into x_a1 values('A1','B1',4);
insert into x_a2 values('A1','B1',null);
insert into x_a2 values('A1','B1',null);
insert into x_a2 values('A1','B1',null);
insert into x_a2 values('A1','B1',null);
```

So, I tried updating the same using this query: -

```
update x_a2 a2
set col_id= a1.col_id
from x_a1 a1
where a1.col1 =a2.col1
and a1.col2 =a2.col2
```

But the output is coming out as : - 
Select * from x_a2

```
col1   col2   Col_id
----------------------
A1     B1      1
A1     B1      1
A1     B1      1
A1     B1      1
```

Desired Output is: -

```
col1   col2   Col_id
----------------------
A1     B1      1
A1     B1      2
A1     B1      3
A1     B1      4
```

Comment: simply delete the rows( or truncate) from `x_a2` and insert from `x_a1` Why do you want two tables with the same data by the way?

Comment: well there is some requirement in the product

Comment: In that case you can always suggest your product that it's waste of resources having two tables that store exactly the same data. There are always better options to solve the problem you are trying to solve than sticking with an inefficient plan. If they still insist on having the second table, simply delete the entries and repopulate it from the first table since you're not going to lose any information/data.